# 2 near identical URL's integrated with Open Graph tags have separate behaviors when doing a Facebook graph call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Hitting URL #1 (https://graph.facebook.com/280518352029215) associated to this REAL url (http://www.sephora.com/rose-h-cream-P224527) in a browser CORRECTLY outputs this:

```
    {
    about: "What it is:A rich hand moisturizer.What it is formulated to do:Jurlique's Rose Hand Cream deeply hydrates the hands, restoring a soft, supple feeling.What it is formulated WITHOUT:- Parabens- Synthetic Fragrances- Synthetic Dyes- Petro-ChemicalsWhat",
    category: "Product/service",
    description: "What it is:A rich hand moisturizer.What it is formulated to do:Jurlique's Rose Hand Cream deeply hydrates the hands, restoring a soft, supple feeling.What it is formulated WITHOUT:- Parabens- Synthetic Fragrances- Synthetic Dyes- Petro-ChemicalsWhat",
    is_published: true,
    talking_about_count: 0,
    were_here_count: 0,
    id: "280518352029215",
    name: "Sephora: Rose Hand Cream : hands-feet-bath-body",
    link: "http://www.sephora.com/rose-h-cream-P224527",
    likes: 1
    }
```

URL #2 (https://graph.facebook.com/541777132555995) associated to (http://www.sephora.com/green-tea-oil-control-mask-P379853) has a completely different response even though open graph meta tags are identical to URL #1.  This is the response:

```
    error: {
    message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 104
    }
```

additionally, even using an access token I still get this response:

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/541777132555995?access_token=158904350882249|753f74bda2299df3758d21708c7ba34c
    error: {
    message: "Unsupported get request.",
    type: "GraphMethodException",
    code: 100
    }
```

I need URL #2 to have a response like URL #1... with or without an access token, I just need a response similar to URL #1.  Both URL's are coming from the same website and app where their meta tags are programmatically generated, thus I don't see why FB could successfully consume URL #1, but not URL #2... please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we cannot help you without the real url of the object, so as to see what it is!
Have you try both url (the real ones) in facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
to see the difference?

Comment: thanks Sebastien, I've edited to include the Real URL's in the question. Also looked at the debugger already but no luck finding any real differences

Comment: Ok, I think I can make a guess.
The ids you have are not the real ids of these urls. Their ids (and urls) are https://graph.facebook.com/167416306776288 and https://graph.facebook.com/10150829298995120. I mean those are the urls of the opengraph objects made thanks to your og meta data.
But the url: https://graph.facebook.com/280518352029215 is for a facebook 'page' automatically created because someone liked the page. It is not an opengraph object, and both objects are not linked at all, they just referred to the same url.

Comment: And I think what you're looking for is the opengraph objects urls, and those are working well!